# Variable variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variable-variables

according to my knowledge, this feature already exists in PHP. lets look at the following php code:

```
$color = 'red';
$$color = 'dark';
```

### description of the feature:

Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names. That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically.A variable variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable. In the above example, **red**, can be used as the name of a variable.At this point two variables have been defined and stored in the PHP symbol tree: `$color` with contents `"red"` and `$red` with contents `"dark"`.

### my Question

can this be done in java Script?

Comment: It might be convenient sometimes but it's a huge mass!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var color = 'red';
window[color] = 'dark';
console.log(color, red);
```

Comment: I can see in the log that u got it right but can't use the variable `document.getElementById("v").innerHTML= red;` it gives an error `cant set the property of innerHTML of NULL`

Answer (score 6):

Three different techniques come to mind, each with its warnings and (except the second one) uses:

1) You can declare a new variable in JavaScript anywhere in the code using the `var` keyword:

```
var $color = 'red';
```

The variable is actually defined *throughout* the scope in which the `var` occurs, even above the `var` statement — that is, these two functions are identical even though they look slightly different:

```
function foo() {
    doSomething();
    var x = 5;
    x += doSomethingElse();
    return x;
}

function foo() {
    var x;

    doSomething();
    x = 5;
    x += doSomethingElse();
    return x;
}
```

This is because all `var`s take effect when the context for the function is created, not where they appear in the code. More: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

2) If you just assign to a free symbol that's never been declared anywhere, you'll create an implicit global variable (not one constrained to the current scope), which is generally a bad idea. More: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

3) Another thing you can do is have an object which is a container for various variables you want to track. You can create new properties on the object just by assigning them:

```
var data = {};    // A blank object
data.foo = "bar"; // Now `data` has a `foo` property
```

This technique is particularly handy when you need to track data that your script is completely unaware of, for instance based on user input, because you can use either dotted notation and a literal as above (`data.foo`), or you can use bracketed notation and a string (`data["foo"]`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression, so all of these create a `foo` property on `data`:

```
// Dotted notation with a literal
data.foo = 42;

// Bracketed notation with a literal string
data["foo"] = 42;

// Bracketed notation with a string coming from a variable
s = "foo";
data[s] = 42;

// Bracketed notation with a string coming from an expression
s = "o";
data["f" + s + s] = 42;
```

Comment: can't find what I'm looking for in your answer. thanks anyway.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi: I think the third option above is the closest to the PHP concept you describe in your edit. `s = "foo";`, then using `s` as the name of a variable: `data[s] = 42;` means that `data.foo` has the value `42`.

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi: The third option is the way you are supposed to do it. Don't create a shitload of globals! But if you really need to, you can store those vars in `window` instead of `data` - that'll make them global.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I want to assign an object to the variable `window[color]=document.getElementById("v")` and I will use it several times in different places in my code. therefore the third way won't do it for me I suppose.AM I right?

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi: It works just fine. `window` is an object, like my `data` example. Assuming that `color` is a variable containing the string `'red'`, for instance, then `window[color]=document.getElementById("v")` will happily create a global variable `red` which refers to the element. Globals are properties of the `window` object, so `color = 'red';` `window[color] = 42;` `alert(window.red); /* alerts 42 */` `alert(red); /* Also alerts 42 */` `alert(window[color]); /* ALSO alerts 42 */` It's best to avoid global variables, but if you must use them, that will work.