# Remove double quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove double quotes from array in JavaScript?

Suppose this is an array

```
enc= ["WPA2", "WPA2", "WPA2", "WPA2", "WPA1", "WEP", "WPA2", "WPA2", "WPA1", "WEP", "WEP"]
```

Thanks

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have an array of strings, and you want an array of...? Or are your array elements actually more like `"\"WPA2\""`?

Comment: The double quotes are string delimiters, how do you want to remove them?

Comment: `enc= [WPA2, WPA2, WPA2, WPA2, WPA1, WEP, WPA2, WPA2, WPA1, WEP, WEP]`. This is your desired outcome??

Comment: If you remove the double quotes your going to receive an error.

Comment: What type do you expect to get in your array? What's your real need?

Answer (score 25):

There are no double quotes in that array. The quotes just delimit the string literals, when they are parsed into strings they don't have quotes in them.

---

If you wanted to remove all the quotes from a string which actually had some in it:

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, "");  // RegEx to match `"` characters, with `g` for globally (instead of once)
```

You could do that in a loop over an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < enc.length; i++) {
    enc[i] = enc[i].replace(/"/g, "");
}
```

---

If you wanted to change the source code so that it looked like:

```
enc= [WPA2, WPA2, WPA2, WPA2, WPA1, WEP, WPA2, WPA2, WPA1, WEP, WEP]
```

… (and populated the array with some predefined variables) then you would be too late. The source code would have already been parsed by the JavaScript engine.

To get at variables when you have their names in strings, you would have to enter the murkey world of [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869187/variable-variables-in-javascript) and are better off refactoring to use object properties (or going direct to an array).

Comment: What is your intention? you declace a variable and you do not use it. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

This would be an error.
Quotes are needed to mark the content beeing a string, not a variable.

Comment: It wouldn't be a syntax error; they are all valid identifier names. It might be a *reference* error, but only if they were undeclared

Comment: @Thomas Junk                                                                                                 I know but i want to store arraly like {De:3,EN::5 }; then how is possible ..Please help